# Importing and method call

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to asp, and I cannot figure out how to the syntax for importing and adding a date object in the Default.aspx file.
The goal is to capture the get method and run the query. Here is what I've got:

```
 <%
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    string add = Request.QueryString["add"];
    if (add != null && add.Length > 0)
    {
        Response.Output.Write("add = " + add);
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourconnstringInWebConfig"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        try
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Conn = conn;
                //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BuildVersion Values (@id, @dbVersion, @versionDate, @modifiedDate)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "2");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbVersion", "10.00.80404.00");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@versionDate", "4/4/2008 12:00:00 AM   ");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@modifiedDate", "4/4/2008 12:00:00 AM  ");
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Output.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.close();
            }
        }

    }
 %>
```

I need to learn how to do it inline as well as how to do it properly in a separate cs file. Thanks.

Comment: This is not Asp classic. This is ASP.NET and C#. And it's somewhat hard to figure out what you're asking since your question is a bit broad.

Comment: Let's see if this makes sense: I'm trying to make a web app in web developer 2010 in c# ASP.NET. I'm able to handle the get method as shown above. However, I do not know how to add the logic to perform a query upon the request. The first problem is how to import the sqlClient. Thanks